# ListView scroll up and down resets data in it

Tags: android, listview

I have developed an app were when the user launches the application it opens and download data using async task into listview. Every row has a like button which is black. Users can like an item by clicking on the heart button and it turns red, When the user scrolls down and comeback to the item he/she liked, the liked button goes back to the black colour. I want the red colour to stay even when the user scrolls down/up and come back to the liked item.

This is my Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapterSup extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();



public ListViewAdapterSup(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView artisteTV;
    TextView likesCountTV;
    ImageButton artisteLike;

}

ViewHolder holder;



public View getView(final int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {
    itemView = null;

    if (itemView == null) {


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sups_list_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();



    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    holder.artisteTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artiste_name);
    holder.likesCountTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count);

    holder.artisteLike= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.art_like);

    itemView.setTag(holder);

    }

     else{

         holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();

     }



    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    holder.artisteTV.setText(resultp.get(Artiste.NAME));
    holder.likesCountTV.setText(resultp.get(Sups.LIKES_COUNT));


        holder.artisteLike.setTag(holder);
            holder.artisteLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                                resultp = data.get(position);

                                if(holder.artisteLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.artisteLike.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp).getConstantState())){
                                resultp = data.get(position);

                                    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    new LikeSup().execute();
                                    holder.artisteLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp);

                                    }

                            }

                                else if(holder.artisteLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(holder.artisteLike.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_24dp).getConstantState())){
                                    resultp = data.get(position);

                                        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
                                        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

                                            Toast.makeText(context,"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                            }
                                        else
                                        {

                                        new UnLikeSup().execute();
                                       holder.artisteLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);

                                        }
                                    }

                            }



                }
            });


    return itemView;
}
```

}

Comment: The views get recycled, you have to set each one every time. Show the code.

Comment: The key to your question is on your `Adapter`, when you create each view of your List. As the List gets recycled, android reads this code every time. You should save the state of each row and colour red or black according to its state.

Comment: @Rafael How do i save the state of each row

Comment: I think the ViewHolder pattern may fix this

Comment: @Cricket how should i customised my ViewHolder

Comment: Show us what you have tries so far. The adapter code, the actual problem. The whole statement cannot be your problem because no one can do your Homework for you.

Comment: @Shubham please check my edited question i added the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are using a normal ListView then make sure you "pack" the list item in an object and change the state of that object in this case, liked or unliked, when the user clicks the like button.

In case you are using a recyclable ListView then as the others mentioned in the comments your view is getting recycled so no matter what you are getting the same object in every row.

Go here to learn the ViewHolder pattern, where your list can have unique elements but at the same time recycle them for fast scrolling and better resource management.
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Here you can learn how to implement it, it has a picture of whats going on so you can visualize it.
http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/03/12/recycling-views-listview

Comment: You are setting itemView to null at the very first line and then checking if its null...

Comment: The way you implemented it is not wrong but you just have copy pasted so you don't know what is going on. Go through your code again.

Answer (score 0):

first,in the getview() method ,you should not set the itemView to null;you should understand the recycle mechanism,the "itemView "(called convertView) is the current display view,it hold several item views;

second,

> Users can like an item by clicking on the heart button and it turns red, When the user scrolls down and comeback to the item he/she liked, the liked button goes back to the black colour. I want the red colour to stay even when the user scrolls down/up and come back to the liked item.

```
1,about ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
```

you should change the data struct that the arraylist contain a databean for example:

```
public class AlbumBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String likedCount;
private boolean isLiked; 
private String picUrl;
// get() set()  method
...................
```

}

```
2,in your ListViewAdapterSup ,you should define a var  boolean isLiked;

3,the example as i do

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null || !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder)) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.buyah_chosen_album_detail_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productImg = (ScaledRemoteImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_img);
            holder.productDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
            holder.productTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
            holder.favoriteCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_count);
            holder.multiple = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_content);
            holder.priceAndScoreView = (BuyahPriceAndScoreView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price_score_view);
            holder.favoriteCount.setOnClickListener(this);
            convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (holder != null) {
        final ChosenAlbumDetailBean product = getItem(position);
        holder.favoriteCount.setTag(R.id.price, holder);
        holder.favoriteCount.setTag(R.id.favorite_count, product);
        holder.productImg.setTag(R.id.product_img, product);
        holder.priceAndScoreView.setPriceAndScore(product, 16);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(product.getPic(), holder.productImg);
        holder.productTitle.setText(product.getTitle());

        holder.favoriteCount.setText(product.getLiked());
        if (product.getIs_liked()) {
            isFavorited = true;
            holder.favoriteCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.buyah_middle_favorite_selected, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            isFavorited = false;
            holder.favoriteCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.buyah_middle_favorite_unselect, 0, 0, 0);
        }

    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    ChosenAlbumDetailBean product = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.favorite_count:
            ClickDurationController.controlClickDuration(v);
            if (!UserInfoCommon.getInstance().isLogined()) {
                if (buyahChosenAdapterNeedLoginListener != null) {
                    buyahChosenAdapterNeedLoginListener.onBuyahChosenAdapterClick();
                }
            } else {
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(R.id.price);
                product = (ChosenAlbumDetailBean) v.getTag(R.id.favorite_count);
                boolean isFavorite = product.getIs_liked();
                int currentFavoriteCount = Integer.valueOf(holder.favoriteCount.getText().toString());
                if (isFavorite) {
                    isFavorite = false;
                    isFavorited = false;
                    holder.favoriteCount.setText(currentFavoriteCount - 1 + "");
                    holder.favoriteCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.buyah_middle_favorite_unselect, 0, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    isFavorite = true;
                    isFavorited = true;
                    holder.favoriteCount.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.buyah_middle_favorite_selected, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.favoriteCount.setText(currentFavoriteCount + 1 + "");
                }
                product.setIs_liked(isFavorite);
                product.setLiked(holder.favoriteCount.getText().toString());

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

hope to help you!